# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar columnas en EXCEL que están separadas?

Tags: excel, ordenar

Necesito ordenar varias columnas de un archivo de Excel que están separadas. Para las columnas que están una al lado de la otra, no hay problema porque es seleccionar el rango (como ejemplo de la columna A a la C si quisieras ordenar los clientes en función del número de operaciones). En el momento en que quiero ordenar los clientes según su valor nominal, al seleccionar el rango A:D, también selecciona la columna C, que ahora ya no me interesa. Así que necesito una fórmula que ordene las columnas que me interesan y que no las incluya todas.

He estado usando esta fórmula para el primer ejemplo (fácil): =SORT(A2:C12;3;-1;FALSE)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando trato de ordenar las columnas A, B y D, sucede lo siguiente (y no aparece la columna C):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que aplicación practica tendría? Si lo piensas bien, si dejas sin ordenar una columna toda tu información se desordena pues cada "cliente" siempre debe tener toda la información correspondiente a su registro.

Comment: La cuestión es que me interesa ordenar y presentar unas tablas en función de varios criterios distintos, por lo que necesito que X columnas no aparezcan.

Comment: *me interesa ordenar y presentar unas tablas en función de varios criterios distintos, por lo que necesito que X columnas no aparezcan* En ese caso lo mejor son diferentes tablas dinámicas, cada una solo con los campos que te interesan y ordenadas cada una según tus necesidades.

Comment: Necesito formularlo, no me vale con tablas dinamicas